# Open a file, take screenshot of the file and close it, using a Send To shortcut

Tags: powershell

As the title suggests, I want to run a PowerShell script from File Explorer using the Send To menu. Setting up the shortcut and getting the script to start is fine. The main issue is that after opening a file, the screenshot is of File Explorer (probably because I'm using "AllScreens". If you can translate Micrsoft Help files into plain English, please tell me what I *should* be using), not of the file that was opened. Another issue is that I cannot close the file. I tried using Stop-Process, but

I see plenty of related code, but can't get what I want working.

```
Param([string]$SourceFile) #Get the file name via the Send To shortcut, Powershell script runs minmized

Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'

$ConsolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($ConsolePtr, 0)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyNameSystem.Drawing

Start-Process $SourceFile -Wait

$Screen = [Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens

$ScreenTop    = ($Screen.Bounds.Top    | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
$ScreenLeft   = ($Screen.Bounds.Left   | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
$ScreenWidth  = ($Screen.Bounds.Right  | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
$ScreenHeight = ($Screen.Bounds.Bottom | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

$Bounds   = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($ScreenLeft, $ScreenTop, $ScreenWidth, $ScreenHeight)
$BMP      = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap ([int]$Bounds.Width), ([int]$Bounds.Height)
$Graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($BMP)

$Graphics.CopyFromScreen($Bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $Bounds.Size)

$FileName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($SourceFile)

$BMP.Save("$PSScriptRoot\$FileName.png")

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

Stop-Process $SourceFile -Force

$Graphics.Dispose()
$BMP.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use passthru to get the process (with that you can close the window)
And use RECT for the position of the window. It should work like that:

```
$SourceFile = "FilePath"
$ScreenshotPath = "C:\Temp"

Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'

#Load assemlny
Add-Type @"

    using System;

    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Window {

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    }

    public struct RECT

    {

    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner

    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner

    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner

    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner

    }

"@
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$proc = Start-Process $SourceFile -PassThru

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

#Get current location of windows
$Handle = $proc.MainWindowHandle
$Rectangle = New-Object RECT
[Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)

$Bounds   = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($Rectangle.Left,$Rectangle.Top, $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom)
$BMP      = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap ([int]$Bounds.Width), ([int]$Bounds.Height)
$Graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($BMP)

$Graphics.CopyFromScreen($Bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $Bounds.Size)

$FileName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($SourceFile)

$BMP.Save((Join-Path -Path $ScreenshotPath -ChildPath "$FileName.png")) 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1


$proc.CloseMainWindow()
$proc.Close()
$Graphics.Dispose()
$BMP.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks you so much guiwhatsthat! (great name , btw!) I edited the Start-Process line to maximise the window with ``` -WindowStyle Maximized```, but I wonder if it's possible to scroll to the bottom while taking screenshots? My guess is using 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{PGDN}") is one way to do it, but I don't know how to implement it in a loop or when the loop should stop.

Comment: Also, a nice feature would be get rid of the title bar, scroll bars and taskbar in the screenshot(s). I had a look around and found SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA). Could it be used?

Comment: I don't know about these topics. If you have trouble finding a solution, then I would recommend to open a new questions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I really appreciate your help!